# In postgresql, how to use 'where' in Knex.raw as the data to 'where' is coming from a subquery?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

This is my code
I want to use regexp_replace so I am trying to use Knex.raw but I am finding it difficult to use where clause

```
  async function test () {
  let usernameData = {
      oldUserName: 'MobileOpsteam',
      newUserName: 'cool'
  }
  const oldUserNameRegex = `@${usernameData.oldUserName}(?![a-zA-Z0-9])`

  const newUserName = `@${usernameData.newUserName}`

  let subQuery = await knex.select('id').from('user_notification').where('title', 'like', `%${usernameData.oldUserName}%`)
  let result = await knex.raw((`update user_notification set title = regexp_replace(title, ${oldUserNameRegex}, ${newUserName}, 'g')`).whereIn('id', subQuery))
// let result = await knex.raw(`update user_notification set title = regexp_replace(title, ${oldUserNameRegex}, ${newUserName}, 'g') where id in ${subQuery}`)
  console.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
  // subquery builder is not awaited, since query should not be executed separately
  let subQuery = knex.select('id')
    .from('user_notification').where('title', 'like', `%${usernameData.oldUserName}%`)

  let result = await knex('user_notification')
      .update({
          title: knex.raw(
                     `regexp_replace(??, ${oldUserNameRegex}, ${newUserName}, 'g')`, 
                      ['title'])
      }).whereIn('id', subQuery)
```

Basically `knex.raw()` cannot be appended with any additional `.where(...)` etc. because raw builder doesn't have any information about the syntactical elements of the SQL it contains.